# Mockito mock method with comparing parameters - Misplaced argument matcher detected here

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to mock a method of EntityPersistor

```
T getSingleResultFromTypedQuery(String queryString, Map<String, Object> params);
```

I want to check if queryString matches a specific queryString and if params contains a specific value. If those two conditions are true, I want to return an specific object xy.

I'm new to mocking and mockito, but I tried to achieve this with two ArgumentMatcher inside the when() call.

```
EntityPersistor<UserEntity> entityPersistorMocked = mock(EntityPersistorStub.class);

when(entityPersistorMocked.getSingleResultFromTypedQuery(argThat(new ArgumentMatcher<String>() {
        @Override
        public boolean matches(Object o) {
            return "SELECT u FROM UserEntity u where u.username = :u".equals(o.toString());
        }
    }), argThat(new ArgumentMatcher<Map<String, Object>>() {
        @Override
        public boolean matches(Object o) {
            HashMap<String, Object> params = (HashMap<String, Object>) o;
            if (params.containsKey('u') && params.get('u').toString().equals("hans")) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    })))
            .thenAnswer(new Answer<UserEntity>() {
                @Override
                public UserEntity answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                    UserEntity user = new UserEntity();
                    user.setUserId(1);
                    user.setDisplayName("Dummy User");
                    user.setUsername("hans");
                    user.setPassword("pass");
                    return user;
                }
            });
```

compiles successfull but won't run:

> ```
> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
> ```
>
> Misplaced argument matcher detected here:

how can I fix that? or is there a better way to mock a method and define a specific return case (if param 1 eq x and param 2 eq y)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just do:

```
Answer<UserEntity> answer = new Answer<UserEntity>() {
   public UserEntity answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
       String queryString = (String) invocation.getArgument(0);
       Map params = (Map) invocation.getArgument(1);
       if ("foo".equals(queryString) && params.containsKey("bar")) {
          return x;
       } else {
          return y;
       }
   }
};
when(mock.getSingleResultFromTypedQuery(anyString(), any(Map.class)).thenAnswer(answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simplify your code a bit by doing simply:

```
EntityPersistor<UserEntity> entityPersistorMocked = mock(EntityPersistorStub.class);

HashMap<String, Object> expectedParams = (HashMap<String, Object>) o;
expectedParams.put("u", "hans");


UserEntity user = new UserEntity();
user.setUserId(1);
user.setDisplayName("Dummy User");
user.setUsername("hans");
user.setPassword("pass");
return user;

when(entityPersistorMocked.getSingleResultFromTypedQuery("SELECT u FROM UserEntity u where u.username = :u", expectedParams)).thenReturn(user);
```

just make sure that the values in your map can be equal-checked (in your case with strings it should work but for some arbitrary object that hasn't an equal method mockito will not find out the object your are passing in is the same (value) as the expected one..